# Как можно получить 'src' из страницы на Python?

Tags: python, html, веб-программирование, selenium

Хочу вывести ссылку для загрузки видео, находиться в атрибуте src в коде ЭЛЕМЕНТА страницы.

Перепробовал кучу библиотек для работы с сайтами, ничего не помогает. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Может есть шанс хотябы на Selenium сделать код?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если речь про Twitch, то почему бы не просто взять какой-нибудь готовый youtube-dl / yt-dlp?

Comment: Дайте ссылку на сайт, с которого собираетесь парсить

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\webdr\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get('https://clips.twitch.tv/EntertainingNeighborlyStapleSMOrc-b5vZvPfaZI8zqj3C?lang=ru') # Ссылка на страницу с видео 


elem  =  browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,  '.video-ref') # Родитель, в котором лежит видео 
video = elem.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'video') # Поиск в родителе видео по тегу


link_video = video.get_attribute('src') # Получаем ссылку на видео
```